# Python check json for keys and values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to write a code in python that takes a json file as input. It can contain other dictionaries, lists, etc.. I am trying to print they keys, my problem is that the keys that have the same name I get printed only the last key and value. Also the nested keys are printed as values. Lastly I use the len()to count how many times the same key appeared but something is wrong with my code...

Code:

```
#open data
import json

with open('list.txt') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)

    #find key
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
         print("Key : {}, Value : {}".format(key, value))

    print("\n")

    #how many time you found the key
    for key,value in my_dict.items():
         print("{} found : ".format(key),len(key))
```

Json txt:

```
{
    "QQ": "text",
    "WW": "text",
    "EE": "text1",
    "EE": "text2",
    "EE": "text3",
    "RR": ["text", "text"],
    "TT": 99,
    "YY": {
        "QQ": ["text", "text"],
        "TT": 99
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key : QQ, Value : text
Key : WW, Value : text
Key : EE, Value : text3
Key : RR, Value : ['text', 'text']
Key : TT, Value : 99
Key : YY, Value : {'QQ': ['text', 'text'], 'TT': 99}


QQ found :  2
WW found :  2
EE found :  2
RR found :  2
TT found :  2
YY found :  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't allow you to have multiple key-value pairs with the same key. It therefore only lets you access the most recently updated (i.e. last in file) version of the key-value pair. You should put `"text1"`, `"text2"`, and `"text3"` in a list assigned to `"EE"` if you want them all to be accessible though `"EE"`.

Comment: Oh, okay so basically a key in json can not be found more than once?

Comment: @NoemonGR exactly

Comment: @NoemonGR, If that helps, please mark my answer as accepted, and upvote if you haven't already. Thanks!